# how to set Hive reduce operator since reduce operator is always is 0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am trying to upload data to hive rc and orc file but number of reducer is always 0. I try to to set the reducer in hive with set mapred.reducer.tasks=1 but it does not work. I found internet that default size per reducer is 1G so i try to upload 3G data so reducer would be at least 2. what i have to work reduce operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks=99;
set hive.exec.reducers.max=99;
```

However it is likely that your tasks do not require a reducer.

Comment: Yes you are right, in my case do not require reducer.

Answer (score 1):

I would need more information about the query to know for sure but my guess is that the query you are running is a map only job, thus not requiring any reducers. You can add a DISTRIBUTE BY statement to force Hadoop to use reducers. For example,

```
SELECT txn_id FROM table;
```

will be a map only job. You can force Hive to add a reduce step by adding this clause.

```
SELECT txn_id FROM table
DISTRIBUTE BY txn_id;
```